# Why wasn't I listed for putting a question on-hold?

Tags: support

I flagged [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/218584/104515) question as 'Unclear what you're asking' due to the lack of information and because it sounded like it was asking Supercell a question (see my comment).

When I revisited the question, it was on hold. No surprise there. However, I wasn't on the list of people who closed it. But my [flagging history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/104515) says otherwise.

**So why aren't I on the list of people who flagged the post?**

My current ideas include:

- You do not see yourself in the list of people who closed it
- Flaggers only identify the posts, those who vote in the review queue are listed
- Only a limited number of names can be displayed and I was the unlucky one out
- Only users with over `x` rep are displayed
- Stack Exchange doesn't like me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You weren't listed as one of the people who closed the post because you didn't actually vote to close it, you flagged the post, which is a separate action.

Once you have enough reputation to actually cast close votes instead of flags, your name will show up in that list if a question is closed. You will need 3,000 reputation on Arqade to be able to cast close votes on a question.

Comment: Seems like my thought no. 2 was correct. Thankyou for the clarification. Accepted in 10 mins.

Comment: Well, it's not just people who vote to close using the review queue, it's people who vote to close regardless (it is an action that can be done when viewing the question itself, when you have sufficient rep, along with also being able to close via the queue.)